# Joomla online shopping extension

Tags: joomla, e-commerce, shopping-cart, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I am developing an e-commerce website with Joomla 2.5. It should have following 2 features.

1. It should allow the shop owner maintain the shop online by displaying his products
2. It should allow other users to log in using an account and upload there products

So what are the extensions available for these purposes? I already checked virtueMart but not quite sure if the 2nd feature is available in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are so many Virtuemart product display extensions available, you have to use the extension according to your need. For example if you want to display different product listings of top products, features products, custom products and more than Product Viewer for Virtuemart is the best option for you. If you want to display product in category with price, description, and image then So VMSlider is best for you. For the details of the other extension visit http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying few of the shopping modules available in [link](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the second feature isn't available in any shopping extensions for Joomla. However, I have only ever tested the free ones such as VirtueMart, JoomShopping, redSHOP and HikaShop, so one of the commercial extensions might have this feature.

Else you might have to use an [Auction](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/auction) extension, however they are all commercial, apart from 1, but it's for Joomla 1.5.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah the second feature is not supported by any of the shopping extensions so far.so thought of going on with a classified module.